# Peculiar Behavior - Launcher app uninstalled automatically [Rooted phone]

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-launcher

I have rooted the Android phone for one of the Projects and installed my own Launcher Application. 
I have also written a piece of code which will check for Launcher updates. If there are any updates for Launcher, the app will be downloaded and installed automatically (rooted phone, so I bypass Package Manager permissions).

The process is smooth and all works well.

However, the moment I restart the Phone, the Launcher app goes back to it's original version and updated Launcher is not found.

This is how I verified the peculiar behavior:

1. Installed custom Launcher app in /system/app folder.
2. Rebooted the phone, Selected customer launcher to be the Default launcher.
3. Installed updated launcher from "adb install -r launcher.apk" . Installation was successful.
4. Updated launcher was seen in "Settings -> Application Manager -> Downloaded Apps" section.
5. Reboot the Phone.

The launcher update disappeared after reboot!

Please advice me on how to update the Launcher? Is this any known issue in Android? 
I am using Android 4.1.1 OS version and a Samsung Phone for test.

Answer (score 0):

After doing research on the issue, I found that Android uninstalls any System app automatically, if the versionCode is same. 
I changed the versionCode of the launcher app and installed it through adb install command, rebooted the phone and voila, the app was still available.

I tried the test with more test apps and noticed this behavior that versionCode has to be updated else app is uninstalled automatically.

Hope it helps others!